# How can I play webm streaming video in an MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have URLs to webm video files. How do I play them within an MPMoviePlayerController?
I tried this

```
NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.hack.video];
MPMoviePlayerController* mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
mPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
mPlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[mPlayer.view setFrame:self.videoView.bounds];
[mPlayer prepareToPlay];
[mPlayer play];
[self.videoView addSubview:mPlayer.view];
self.videoView = mPlayer.view;
```

This works fine when using an MP4 URL but only shows the background color with webm videos.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

From the `MPMoviePlayerController` doc ,

> Supported Formats
>
> This class plays any movie or audio file supported in iOS. This
>   includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie
>   files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4,
>   .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:
>
> ```
> H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
>
> MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)
> ```
>
> If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen
>   with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this
>   class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio
>   Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.

It appears webm format is not supported by iOS.

Comment: This is not an answer. Other apps find ways around.

Comment: @DavidL.Rodgers  I don't see why this is not an answer.Other apps which find ways around don't use `MPMoviePlayerController` for this task. They use `AVFoundation`. This question is about `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support other codecs, try [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org).

Comment: Is this Obj-C? It looks like server code. I'm trying to do this in the app.

Comment: ffmpeg is a huge collection of video frameworks... it can do almost anything, but there is a pretty big engineer overhead to figure out what to compile etc. I haven't ever done anything with ffmpeg on iOS, but I assume it has been done.

Answer (score 0):

The video must be in the format supported by iOS. WebM format is different from the acceptable formats to play video in iOS. You  may need to convert these video files to play using MPMoviePlayerController.

iOS supports many industry-standard video formats and compression standards, including the following:

- H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second,
  Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC
  audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov
  file formats.
- H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second,
  Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48
  kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats.
- MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per
  second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz,
  stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats.
- Numerous audio formats, including the ones listed in “Audio
  Technologies”.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW6

Comment: This is not an answer.